# CRON to Run on Weekdays

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cronjob set to run as

```
3 6 10 * 1-6 wget'http://...'
```

How will this execute ? I intend to run it at 6:03 AM on the 10th Of Every Month expect on Sundays.

I am confused as it ran on Saturday, even when the date was not 10th.

Please advise if there is an error with my command or could it be something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have this setup, your command will execute EITHER when the day of the week is 1-6 OR when the day of month is 10.

Comment: Is there a way I can run it as intended ? That is on every 10th but if its a Sunday then don't run.

Comment: How about putting your command inside a script that checks if it is a Sunday, and only running the command if not.  Then, setup the cron job like:  
3 6 10 * * /path/to/script